# NetLogo selecting a value from a matrix

Tags: netlogo

I have a model in which dispersing male animals challenge resident males for their territory. The dispersing male has a certain probability of winning based on his age and the age of the resident male being challenged. In other words, I ask the model to compare the age of the male agent to that of the male being challenged and then select a probability of winning. For example:

```
                let d random-float 1
                if [age] of resident-male < [age] of dispersing-male
                [
                  set prob-winning 0.7
                ]
                if [age] of resident-male = [age] of dispersing-male
                [
                  set prob-winning 0.5 
                ]
                if [age] of resident-male > [age] of dispersing-male
                [
                  set prob-winning 0.3
                ]
                if d < prob-winning
                [
                  ask resident-male
                  [                      
                    die
                  ]
                ]
```

I have data (see below) that provides the probability of winning in a matrix with age (years) of dispersing male (3 columns) and age of resident male (13 rows).

```
    4    5    6
3   1    1    1
4   0.5  0.55 0.65
5   0.45 0.5  0.55
6   0.4  0.45 0.5
7   0.35 0.4  0.45
8   0.4  0.45 0.5
9   0.45 0.5  0.55
10  0.5  0.55 0.6
11  0.7  0.75 0.8
12  1    1    1
13  1    1    1
14  1    1    1
15  1    1    1
```

It seems really inefficient to use a bunch of `if` statements to determine whether the male wins. Does anyone know whether there is a way to input the matrix with the probability values that I can refer to during the challenge procedure? Or any other more efficient way of selecting a specific value from a two-dimensional matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use the [NetLogo array or table extensions for that](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arraystables.html), but in your case, a list of lists could also do the trick:

```
to-report prob-winning [ age-res age-dis ]
  let probabilities [
    [ 3   1    1    1    ]
    [ 4   0.5  0.55 0.65 ]
    [ 5   0.45 0.5  0.55 ]
    [ 6   0.4  0.45 0.5  ]
    [ 7   0.35 0.4  0.45 ]
    [ 8   0.4  0.45 0.5  ]
    [ 9   0.45 0.5  0.55 ]
    [ 10  0.5  0.55 0.6  ]
    [ 11  0.7  0.75 0.8  ]
    [ 12  1    1    1    ]
    [ 13  1    1    1    ]
    [ 14  1    1    1    ]
    [ 15  1    1    1    ]
  ]
  report item (age-dis - 3) first filter [ first ? = age-res ] probabilities 
end
```

The last line uses a combination of [`first`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#first) and [`filter`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#filter) to find the row corresponding to the age of the resident male, and then maps the age of the displacing male (i.e., `age-dis - 3`) to the right "column" in the table.

You can use it like this:

```
let p prob-winning [age] of resident-male [age] of dispersing-male
if random-float 1.0 < p [
  ask resident-male [ die ]
]
```

There is no validation in the code, so if you give it an age that is not part of the table, you will get an error.